# No route matches [PATCH] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create edit action.But when I submit edit, browser show me an error.I can not find where the error

routes.rb

```
resources :posts
root 'posts#index'
```

helper form_for who writes the error

```
<%= form_for :post, url: root_path(@post), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

how fix?
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply have:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

Rails will create proper action path and use proper HTTP method automatically.

Your example doesn't work directly because you used wrong URL helper. You don't want to route to root path, but to posts#update action, so it should be: `url: post_path(@post)`.

You should also set `@post` variable to hold actual instance of `Post` that you want to update:

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: why?why not as example?I forgot to say that it is a form of action 'edit'

Comment: @vveare138 Because it's much simpler to read and idiomatic in Rails. Your example doesn't work directly because you used wrong URL helper. You don't want to route to root path, but to `posts#update` action, so it should be: `url: post_path(@post)`.

Comment: still error No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: @vveare138 first thing, I updated my answer (it should be `post_path`, not `edit_post_path`. Second thing - you probably don't set your `@post` instance variable in `edit` action. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you submit the form to `root_path(@post)`, but `root_path` is get request.
You can use the following code:

```
<%= form_for @post, url: post_path(@post), method: :put do |f| %>
```

In posts_controller.rb, the edit action is:

```
def edit
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

And Update action is:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)

       format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'edit' }
       format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```